# My University professor copied parts of my assignment for the sample solution. Should he have credited me?

Tags: professorship, plagiarism, exams, homework

So I just saw this and found it kind of funny, a bit weird, I guess flattering and wondered if he should have at least asked me or gave me some credit and is he allowed to do this as the professor? !

I got a 100/100 in this 2000 words assignment for his course and today I decided to see the essay-like solution he posted for everyone to see, and there are complete paragraphs exactly the same as mine, even the commas. I didn't rediscover anything with this assignment, the topic is not new, but the expressions, the writing and the ideas are all mine.

Anyway I am not gonna say anything to him but I did laugh at the thought that if I ever use my answer again in a similar topic imagine if then I am accused of plagiarism from myself and/or him :)

(btw English is not my first language sorry for any mistakes)

Comment: He should give you credit. Period. The more if he is so fond of your submission.

Comment: He may not be allowed to give you credit, depending on the privacy laws of the area the university is operating in.

Comment: @nick012000 credit not to be intended as marks, I guess, but merely an acknowledgement of the source. Tough I do not think is really necessary in the context.

Comment: @Alchimista Like I said, they may not be legally allowed to publicly acknowledge a particular student's work, depending on the privacy laws of the areas the university is operating in.

Comment: @nick012000 I don't see it, but sometimes things are really weird.

Comment: @Alchimista The student's submissions might be considered confidential information.

Comment: @nick012000 that is the weird part. Anyway I've just started commenting thinking that you took Credits as Marks , Points etc. That wasn't the case. Still, if you are right things are really weird.

Comment: credits as in acknowledgment of him using complete parts of my assignment, not marks since he already gave me full marks anyway. He only omitted parts that I had rephrased from other sources (I included references). Assignments are confidential, so maybe he could have not used my words or he could have said that the solutions are based on students assignments. I think what bothers me mostly is because the Uni is so strict with plagiarism as do all, & he specifically mentions in every assignment that lack of citations will result in consequences &then he does this. "Do as you teach..."

Comment: I didn't see the legal/confidential part, my mistake. Still, he could have asked? But it may indeed be that there is a conflict between legal and ethical requirements in this situation. Unfortunately, legal wins in this case.

Comment: This is just part of life: Many people do not do their jobs (or part of their jobs) well and don't do as they teach. Sometimes, they are in good positions. Sometimes, even worse people (eg abusive professors) are in good positions. That's just life, pick your battles well!

Comment: @nick012000: In which parts of the world it is the legal thing to not notify the student, not asking them for permission, not crediting them but publishing their works? Sounds very weird to me.

Comment: I wonder if this is just a habit of picking the best from the various essays and posting them as representing good solutions, rather than posting them as their own solutions. You could ask about it.

Comment: @user111388: I suspect that FERPA makes it legally tricky to publish names of students when you're a lecturer in the US. This is why you will occasionally see "the following solution was found by a student" rather than "the following solution was found by X Y" in my model solutions. That said, when I use multiple solutions or copy them word by word, I usually ask for permission from the respective students, since it otherwise reeks of plagiarism (although lots of researchers don't seem to regard plagiarism as a real thing when it comes to teaching materials).

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  This may be (I am not in the US), but, as you say, asking for permission should be a given - or, alternativly, not including the student's solution at all if the name is not allowed to be named.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is both flattering and weird. I would call it unprofessional and tacky.

He should have thanked you for the nice answer and asked your permission to post parts of it.

Whether you should have public credit for that work may depend on policies at your school and on how you and the instructor think about the impact of such an announcement on other students.

Do stick with this:

> Anyway I am not gonna say anything to him but I did laugh at the
> thought that if I ever use my answer again in a similar topic imagine
> if then I am accused of plagiarism from myself and/or him :)